# TSQL - Get maximum length of data in every column in every table without Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to get maximum length of data stored in every column in the database? I have seen some solutions which used Dynamic SQL, but I was wondering if it can be done with a regular query.

Comment: Why would dynamic SQL be excluded if it does the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Just query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view for the database, you can get the information out from all columns of all tables in the database if you desire, see the following for more details:

[Information_Schema - COLUMNS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx)

Comment: Is there a reason this was downvoted?  Will the data in the information_schema not return the max length of data that can be stored for each column?  Have I misunderstood the question?  Downvoting without a comment isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: I checked that table, but what it contains is the size of column, not the data stored in it I believe. What I want to achieve is an equivalent of MAX(LEN(Column)) for every column in every table in the database.

Comment: OK, fair enough, I don't think it warranted a downvote though, just a comment clarifying your question would have been sufficient. - "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.", "Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing." - From http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the length of particular data in and *not* the declared length of a column, I am afraid that is not achievable without dynamic SQL.

The reason is that there is only way to retrieve data, and that is the `SELECT` statement. This statement however requires an explicit column, which is part of the statement itself. There is nothing like

```
-- This does not work
select col.Data 
  from Table 
 where Table.col.Name='ColumnName'
```

So the answer is: No.